# Accessing AnswerWizard of Outlook from C# WinFormsApp

Tags: c#, winforms, outlook, office-interop, office-automation

Is there any possibility to access the automatic answering function of Outlook out of my humble WinFormsApp (C#)? To activate it directly out of my App for the time of vacations e.g.
Really appreciate any ideas!
That's what i have but C# doesn't accept the last line:

```
private void Btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 var OLApp = new Outlook.Application();
 object OLAssistent = OLApp.AnswerWizard();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the [AnswerWizard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.outlook._application.answerwizard?view=outlook-pia) property is deprecated. Here is what MSDN documentation states:

> This object, member, or enumeration is deprecated and is not intended to be used in your code.

Instead, you may consider using `EWS` if you deal with Exchange accounts or `Graph API` in case of Office365 accounts configured in Outlook.

Comment: Hi Eugene, thanks for the first idea of using Graph API or EWS. Could u please give me a little bit more of Information on this? Appreciate ur help

Comment: See [Overview of Microsoft Graph](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/overview) for more information.